# How do I validate character type and position within a string using a loop?

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0

I'm currently attempting to validate a string for an assignment so it's imperative that I'm not simply given the answer, if you provide an answer please give suitable explanation so that I can learn from it.

Suppose I have a string

(1234)-1234 ABCD

I'd like to create a loop that will go through that string and validate the position of the "()" as well as the "-" and " ". In addition to the validation of those characters their position must also be the same as well as the data type. Finally, it must be inside a method.

CANNOT USE REGEX

TLDR;
Validate the position of characters and digits in a string, while using a loop inside of a method. I cannot use REGEX and need to do this manually.

Here's what I have so far. But I feel like the loop would be more efficient and look nicer.

```
    public static string PhoneChecker(string phoneStr)
    {
        if (phoneStr[0] == '(' && phoneStr[4] == ')' && phoneStr[5] == ' ' && phoneStr[9] == '-' && phoneStr.Length == 14)
            {

                phoneStr = phoneStr.Remove(0, 1);
                phoneStr = phoneStr.Remove(3, 1);
                phoneStr = phoneStr.Remove(3, 1);
                phoneStr = phoneStr.Remove(6, 1);
                Console.WriteLine(phoneStr);
                if (int.TryParse(phoneStr, out int phoneInt) == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Valid");
                }
            }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
        }
        return phoneStr;
    }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: There's no loop in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still unmaintaible, but still a little better... Note that your code didn't work with your example string (the indexes were off by one).

```
public static bool PhoneChecker(string phoneStr)
{
    if (phoneStr.Length != 16 || phoneStr[0] != '(' || phoneStr[5] != ')' || phoneStr[6] != '-' || phoneStr[11] != ' ')
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!uint.TryParse(phoneStr.Substring(1, 4), out uint phoneInt))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!uint.TryParse(phoneStr.Substring(7, 4), out phoneInt))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // No checks for phoneStr.Substring(12, 4)

    return true;
}
```

Some differences:

- The `Length` check is the first one. Otherwise a short `string` would make the program crash (because if you try to do a `phoneStr[6]` on a `phoneStr` that has a length of 3 you'll get an exception)
- Instead of `int.Parse` I used `uint.Parse`, otherwise `-500` would be acceptable.
- I've splitted the `uint.Parse` for the two subsections of numbers in two different check
- The method returns `true` or `false`. It is the caller's work to write the error message.
- There are various school of thought about early `return` in code: I think that the earlier you can abort your code with a `return false` the better it is. The other advantage is that all the remaining code is at low nesting level (your whole method was inside a big `if () {`, so nesting +1 compared to mine)
- Technically you tagged the question as C#-4.0, but `out int` is C#-6.0
- The main problem here is that stupid constraints produce stupid code. It is rare that Regex are really usefull. This is one of the rare cases. So now you have two possibilities: produce hard-coded unmodifiable code that does exactly what was requested (like the code I wrote), or create a "library" that accepts variable patterns (like the ones used in masked edits, where you can tell the masked edit "accept only `(0000)-0000 AAAA`") and validates the string based on this pattern... But this will be a poor-man's regex, only worse, because you'll have to maintain and test it. This problem will become clear when one month from the release of the code they'll ask you to accept even the `(12345)-1234 ABCD` pattern... and then the `(1234)-12345 ABCD` pattern... and a new pattern every two months (until around one and half years later they'll tell you to remove the validator, because the persons that use the program hate them and it slow their work)

Comment: Thank you so much for this post. This is definitely exactly what I was looking for. I was thinking along these lines but for some reason I kept getting errors which now I see was because I was attempting to put the loop inside a string method rather than a boolean.